# Let's Encrypt on AWS EC2 - domain name mismatch

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I tried to generate a SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt on my EC2 instance with an elastic IP associated to it.

The command I run is

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d mariellaval.com -d www.mariellaval.com
```

Browsing https://mariellaval.com the connection is private, but browsing https://www.mariellaval.com it isn't because the Common Name of the certificate is the DNS of the elastic IP. Why?. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName mariellaval.com:443
  ServerAlias www.mariellaval.com:443
  DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/public
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    path/to/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile path/to/privkey.pem
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSlCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA;
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  <Directory /var/www/path/to/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the .htaccess i force the www, but I temporary disabled it to figure out the certificate problem.

Comment: I'd guess your `www` is not being served by the same virtualhost. Show us your Apache/nginx config.

Comment: I have updated the question with the virtual host file.

Comment: Have you tried ditching the `:443` in ServerName/ServerAlias?

Comment: The command can be simplified to: `./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d mariellaval.com,www.mariellaval.com`